# How often should ducts / furnaces be cleaned?

Tags: furnace, cleaning, ducts, canada

Asking for a house with a dog located in Canada but any general answers would be welcomed.

Comment: Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion.

Comment: How often do you change your filters?  That will have a big impact.

Comment: I change my filters every 3 months.

Answer (score 2):

I rely on keeping the inlet filters clean ( change every month or two) ,so very little dirt gets into the ducts. When replacing the AC evaporator coil ( and the rest of the furnace after 25 years) I did not notice anything on it , although did not examine it.

Answer (score 1):

As often as you detail your car.  The EPA has done studies that suggest there is no benefit to internal air quality by having your ducts cleaned.

Furnace cleaning is slightly different - you should replace the air filter.  The burners in your furnace can also get dirty and work less efficiently.  It probably doesn't hurt to suck the dust off the control board every now and then - you should do this as often as you clean the dust out of your computer.

Paying to have those services done is questionable.

Comment: I'm curious why you immediately suggest cleaning ducts and furnaces as often as one details their car only to follow that up with stating that there's no benefit to having one's ducts cleaned.  Further, many people detail their car with widely varying frequency, perhaps it was your intention to make such a comparison?

Comment: Detailing your car and cleaning your furnace are similar to me in that it isn't strictly required - it likely won't lead to either lasting longer or performing better had you not serviced them.  They both will look better.  You should change the air filter in both your furnace and car on regular intervals.

Comment: "The EPA has done studies that suggest there is no benefit to internal air quality by having your ducts cleaned." Link?

Comment: https://www.epa.gov/indoor-air-quality-iaq/should-you-have-air-ducts-your-home-cleaned