# How often do dryers need to be cleaned out?

Tags: dryer, ducts

Of course I'm aware that the duct/vent should be cleaned, but I'm talking about partially disassembling the dryer itself and cleaning inside of it.

In general, is this an item that should be on my periodic long-term maintenance list?  Or is it typically not needed at all, assuming the ventilation is otherwise in good shape?

Comment: [This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/203309/how-often-should-ducts-furnaces-be-cleaned?rq=1) is related.

Comment: In 40 years of trying to be an adult I have never taken the dryer apart to clean it. I’ve never even considered it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually only when the dryer requires other maintenance work (belt, drum rollers, drum seals, etc.) that involves partially disassembling it, practically speaking. While you're in there, mght as well clean it out. Not really worth tearing it apart just to clean it out, and it should not need that level of cleaning normally.

If it's particularly poorly designed and lets a lot of lint through the filter which it then collects before the duct exits the dryer I suppose you might decide it needs cleaning on some schedule other than "when it breaks." I might decide that it should be replaced with one better designed, though finding that one will be difficult, as hard data on such issues is difficult to come by.